# what are the HTML5 video time rounding thresholds

Tags: html, video, html5-video

I have a database that contains metadata about some videos on my site. One of the things I store is video length which is often a decimal. When I query the database I will round the seconds value so videos that are 10.543 seconds display in a list as 11 seconds. However I've noticed the default html video player will show the video as being 10 seconds when the video loads. I could just floor the true video duration time but I would bet a video that is 10.998 would display as 11 seconds in the default html player.

I'm having trouble finding documentation on what the thresholds are for rounding when it comes to displaying video time durations. And do they change browser to browser?

Answer (score 0):

Its probably not a rounding problem. It's probably a source of truth problem. There is not a standard way to measuring a video duration. Often in a video file there are two or three durations encoded, which can be combined in different ways. For example if you have 10 seconds video, and 11 seconds of audio, but the audio starts 1 second after the video starts what is the duration? 10 (the video track) 11 (the audio track) or 12 (the start of the video track through the end of the audio track)?

Some file formats may encode a duration into the medatadata, which can be calculated using any method, or could even be completely wrong. And the player that reads the file, could choose to ignore the metadata, and calculate it own duration.

And yes, every browser will do it differently for each format.